# Get Latitude and Longitude from Cellular network in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, location

I am looking to get my Latitude and Longitude from my IOS device when my gps is not on or simply when in the setting the user makes the Location to NEVER.

In android I have done this. Since I am new to IOS development is there any way to find out the latitude and longitude .

Please ask for edit or do it if I have framed the question in a wrong way. Hope I have clearly mentioned the issue.

Any help into this is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS only has the [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html) available for get the devices location. The [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html) uses all possible method to get the location of the deice. 
It uses cellular triangulation and only later after it get a GPS fix will it pass these locations to your app.

There is no way to ask [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html) to only use cellular triangulation. You might only get the location based on cellular triangulation and WiFi if you set the [`desiredAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/desiredAccuracy) higher.
So you will always need to use the [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html) which requires the users permission.

There is no other way to get the users location in iOS.

Comment: I am using the cllocationmanager but it seems to be nil. I haven't tried by increasing the accuracy. Thanks for the reply

Comment: You will need to ask the user permission before you will be able to receive location updates from `CLLocationManager`. Either use `- requestWhenInUseAuthorization ` or  `- requestAlwaysAuthorization` depending on your needs.

Comment: I have done that. It give me the latitude and longitude from the gps but when I switch off the location from settings it stops giving me the latitude and longitude

Comment: Post you code, there should be no reason why `CLLocationManager` is `nil`

Comment: Thanks for the response . But is there anything in CoreTelephony.framework that can help me

Comment: Not in the public SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If the user does not give the app permission for location, you will not be able to get it from GPS or cellular.

You might be able to get an rough approximation based upon the IP address, but that will be far from precise.